# VueJS connect unrelated (as in parent/child) components

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

I am exploring vue.js and have a question regarding how a certain problem can be addressed.

My root component has the following template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="stage">
        <map :current-time="currentTime" :recording="recording"></map>
        <player :track="track" :current-time="currentTime"></player>
    </div>
    <control-panel :current-time="currentTime"></control-panel>
</div>
```

Basically, `<player>` component has `<video>` element inside that will load the specified track (with native controls hidden). As such, it will in reality drive the state of the application as the video plays through (current time, playback state, etc). However, `<control-panel>` has a scrub bar and buttons that dictate the video state (play/pause, seek). Obviously, altering this general state in one of the components will affect the other two components (map will also progress according to the current time).

However, I wonder if it would make more sense and whether Vue supports providing references to components so that I could provide `<control-panel>` with a reference to `<player>` so that it could take the state changes directly from it.

Or should this be done in a kind of global-state-passed-down-to-children or a event-broadcast way? Before I am corrected, consider an example where there are two `<player>`s and two `<control-panel>`s that are not hierarchically related but one panelA works with playerA and panelB with playerB. In this case, I think broadcast option falls off the table, correct?

Any suggestions are welcome especially so as I'm just learning Vue.

## Update 1

So after getting a bit more familiar with Vue and hearing back from the community, I think I've come up with a clever solution for syncing `<player>` and `<control-panel>` together. My markup changes to the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="stage">
        <map :current-time="currentTime" :recording="recording"></map>
        <player :track="track" :current-time="currentTime" v-ref:player></player>
    </div>
    <control-panel :current-time="currentTime" v-ref:player-controls :player="$refs.player"></control-panel>
</div>
```

Notice the addition of `v-ref` attributes to `<player>` and `<control-panel>` as well as `:player="$refs.player"` attribute in the latter. This allows me to tie logically together one to another. In my head, it makes sense for control panel to know who or what it is controlling. I'm going to test it out further but, for now, this seems to work.

As for tying together `<map>`, I will end up using broadcasting or simply two-way `currentTime` updated by `<control-panel>`. I'll update this post as I go and will either mark the correct answer or post my own, if different from any of the answers.

## Update 2

Read my answer below. I have been able to resolve my issue successfully using the approach below.

Comment: `$broadcasting` and `$dispatching` could still work with multiple players by passing ids to the components through `props`

Comment: The problem with that approach is that player and control would require id for them to function. However, they are potentially independent components. If I implement them that way, then spawning a player component would require the parent to provide it with an id (because that id would have to be provided to both of them so they know which messages to filter out). Is this generally a problem with all MVVM frameworks? I mean, I love that I can do this dynamic binding and stuff but sometimes, I need fully manual control and it seems its not as straight forward to mix Vue or React with plain JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved taking the approach described in **Update 1**. Because the `<video>` element has a well thought through API, translating it into a reactive component was rather easy (although tiresome).

The wrapper for a video element ended up creating several `computed` attributes in the following manner:

```
'currentTime': {
    cache: false,
    get: function () {
        return this.$els.player.currentTime;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this.$els.player.currentTime = value;
    }
}
```

Property `cache: false` has to be used because the attribute is not tied to a reactive element and needs to be recomputed every time the attribute was queried.

Not making the component fully reactive was intentional. That is, I could have defined needed attributes as `props` with assumption that they could be provided by and synced with the parent. Those attributes would internally be updated whenever `<video>` element would fire a state changing event.

I also ended up propagating `<video>` element's events out to the component's parent using `$emit` method. This was done because the components simply introduced HLS and acted as a state driver. As such, it was acceptable for it not to be fully reactive and mimic the plain `<video>` element.

The controls panel successfully referenced the player component asstated in the **Update 1**. Having received a handle on the player, it was easy to subscribe to its events with `$on` and then simply hit against its computed properties upon the state changing event.

Finally, map was a little bit easier to implement because it followed the more or less simple flow described in all other Vue examples. In reality, the parent of map kept track of current time. This variable was actually updated by the control panel using `:currentTime.sync="currentTime"` attribute. However, to the map, it felt the same as if the parent itself was updating the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to leave them as independent components;

you could then switch out the control-panel component whenever you'd like with another that uses the **same interface**

( just like switching out Stripe with some other payment processor in an e-commerce app )

`$broadcasting` and `$dispatching` works well even with multiple players present as long as you pass along an identifier key with each broadcast/dispatch so that each component that receives the message can immediately determine if it was sent for them.

Comment: I am still resolving this. I may end up using `$broadcasting` for `map`-`video` time sync but I think I've come up with a clever way to sync `video` and `controls`. I'm updating my question with the changes.